# Dax Measure to show previous month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that shows as this:

```
AccountingMonth | AccountingYear | MonthType
January         | 2019           | Other
February        | 2019           | Other
March           | 2019           | Other
April           | 2019           | Other
May             | 2019           | Other
June            | 2019           | Other
July            | 2019           | Other
August          | 2019           | Other
September       | 2019           | Other
October         | 2019           | Other
November        | 2019           | Other
December        | 2019           | Other
January         | 2020           | Other
February        | 2020           | Previous Month
March           | 2020           | Current Month
April           | 2020           | Next Month
```

I am trying to create a measure to just select the previous month. How do I filter using VALUES?

```
GaugePreviousMonthTitle =
VAR SelectedValues =
    VALUES ( Budget[AccountingMonth] ) ------filter for MonthType of Previous Year???
RETURN
    SelectedValues
```

Comment: Is there some reason that you need to use VALUES()?  If I wanted to show the accounting month on the row that you've flagged, I'd just filter the MonthType column.

Comment: I am doing this for a measure calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GaugePreviousMonthTitle =
CALCULATE(
    VALUES ( Budget[AccountingMonth] ), 
    Budget[MonthType]="Pevious Month"
   )
```

An assumption here is that "Previous Month" flag is always unique in the table, and thus will always return only one AccountingMonth. If that's not true, you will need to protect the result from returning multiple values.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it is always unique, so this works perfectly!